# PHP Multidimensional Array - Copy the value to diffrent column key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a problem on this Multidimensional, i need to copy the value to different column key..

here's the array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => item_type
            [1] => product_id
            [2] => sku
            [3] => name
            [4] => baseimage
            [5] => new_name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => product
            [1] => 12629
            [2] => 5102id.22755
            [3] => product name 1
            [4] => CC22755e.jpg
            [5] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => option
            [1] => 12629
            [2] => 22755.Red
            [3] => [Select Color] = Red
            [4] =>
            [5] => 

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => option
            [1] => 12629
            [2] => 22755.Orange
            [3] => [Select Color] = Orange
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
        )



    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => product
            [1] => 12631
            [2] => 0829id.23122
            [3] => product name 2
            [4] => CC23122b.jpg
            [5] =>
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => option
            [1] => 12631
            [2] => 23122.Black
            [4] => [Select Color] = Black
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
        )

)
```

Want this output, is this possible in Multidimensional Array?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => item_type
            [1] => product_id
            [2] => sku
            [3] => name
            [4] => baseimage
            [5] => new_name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => product
            [1] => 12629
            [2] => 5102id.22755
            [3] => product name 1
            [4] => CC22755e.jpg
            [5] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => option
            [1] => 12629
            [2] => 22755.Red
            [3] => [Select Color] = Red
            [4] =>
            [5] => **product name 1**

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => option
            [1] => 12629
            [2] => 22755.Orange
            [3] => [Select Color] = Orange
            [4] => 
            [5] => **product name 1**
        )



    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => product
            [1] => 12631
            [2] => 0829id.23122
            [3] => product name 2
            [4] => CC23122b.jpg
            [5] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => option
            [1] => 12631
            [2] => 23122.Black
            [3] => [Select Color] = Black
            [4] => 
            [5] => **product name 2**
        )

)
```

Hope's it possible...

Comment: Question is not really clear. You could take a look first to PHP multidimensional arrays https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php

Comment: thanks, i already edit

Comment: 2 Array! WHat have you changed? Should we hang aronnd and try and work it out for ourselves, or would you be kind enough to tell us what you want to do. Or we can just move on to a question that has some detail

Comment: @RiggsFolly copy the value to different column key..

Comment: Can I remind you, you are asking us for help

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes bro. need some help.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to do is this?

```
$array[5][3] = $array[3][5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but i think it's about:

```
$name = $arr[0][3];
$arr[0][5] = $name;
```